# launch command from url in Symfony 2.5

Tags: symfony, controller, command

I try this with eg router:debug as a slug but i get :

There are no commands defined in the "router" namespace.

```
/**
     * method
     *
     * @Route("/command-execute/{slug}", name="execute")
     *
     * @Template()
     *
     */
    public function executeAction($slug)
    {
        //TODO add params , add security
        $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);

        $options = array('command' => $slug);

        $input = new ArrayInput($options);
        $output = new StreamOutput(fopen('php://temp', 'w'));

        $application->doRun($input, $output);

        rewind($output->getStream());
        $response =  stream_get_contents($output->getStream());
        //<pre> so the output of string is like an array on layout
        echo '<pre>';

        return array('response'=> $response);

    }
```

Any idea's ?

Comment: @Veve question is not about routing but command execution.

Comment: that's why the title is :launch command from url in Symfony 2.5

Answer (score 1):

Try to find command `->find($slug)` and after it perform `$command->run($input, $output);`

Comment: Here we have a command which runs another command (I think you can adapt it to run from controller):
`$command = $this->getApplication()->find('something:here');
        $arguments = array('force');
        $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
        $returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for everyone's time and many thanks.
I found my error.

1) it is ->run()

2)

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput;
```

I used : `use Symfony\Component\Console\Application` so I made an instance of the wrong object.

Here is the full thing, very handy :

```
namespace xxx\CommandBundle\Controller;

use Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput;


class ComExecuteController extends Controller
{

    public function executeAction($slug)
    {

    $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
    $application = new Application($kernel);
    $application->setAutoExit(false);

    $options = array('command' => $slug);
    $input = new ArrayInput($options);
    $output = new StreamOutput(fopen('php://temp', 'w'));

    $application->run($input, $output);

    rewind($output->getStream());
    $response =  stream_get_contents($output->getStream());
    //<pre> so the output of string is like an array on layout
    echo '<pre>';

    return array('response'=> $response);
    }

}
```